# Show that an entire function is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, constants, entire-functions

Let $f$ be entire and suppose there is a constant $M>0$ such that $|f(z)|>M$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

I think this has something to do with Liouville's theorem but not sure how to go about it!

Comment: What can you say about $\frac{1}{f}$?

Comment: That 1/f > 1/M ?

Comment: $1/|f|<1/M$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Show that $g(z):=\frac1{f(z)}$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** : Apply Liouville theorem to $\frac{1}{f}$.

Comment: How do I know to do that though?

Comment: well to apply Liouville theorem your function needs to be entire and it must be bounded. The intuition is that if you have $|f|>M$ then $|\frac{1}{f}|<1/M$. But after yoi have to verify all the other conditions, since $f \neq 0$, $\frac{1}{f}$ is also entire. So the intuitions was true :).